# Error Occurred [object Object] facebook Open Graph

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

i have some trouble here...

i've just setup a facebook opengraph api on my website, it works well when i using my facebook  account but i get an error message when i test it using my another account...

i get Error Occurred [object Object] when try to access http://www.kiosban.com/jangan-nyalakan-lampu-hazard-dikala-hujan-lebat/ , and when i try to look over my GoogleChrome console i get this error

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined /jangan-nyalakan-lampu-hazard-dikala-hujan-lebat/:1115
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined /jangan-nyalakan-lampu-hazard-dikala-hujan-lebat/:1716
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < index.php:1
Please specify a ShareThis Publisher Key 
For help, contact support@sharethis.com buttons.js:1
Unknown RPC service: undefined apis.google.com/_/apps-static/_/js/gapi/plusone/rt=j/ver=l9xafNDlycA.en_US./sv=1/am=!PemfnfjrL2yI81ARQg/d=1/rs=AItRSTPblCJvoWHsMeVNOsKiKGakP1copQ/cb=gapi.loaded_0:206
Unknown RPC service: undefined apis.google.com/_/apps-static/_/js/gapi/plusone/rt=j/ver=l9xafNDlycA.en_US./sv=1/am=!PemfnfjrL2yI81ARQg/d=1/rs=AItRSTPblCJvoWHsMeVNOsKiKGakP1copQ/cb=gapi.loaded_0:206
Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL http://www.kiosban.com/jangan-nyalakan-lampu-hazard-dikala-hujan-lebat/ from frame with URL http://www.facebook.com/plugins/login.php?add_to_profile=false&api_key=384945498218921&channel=http%3A%2F%2Fstatic.ak.facebook.com%2Fconnect%2Fxd_arbiter.php%3Fversion%3D6%23cb%3Df1382a12d%26origin%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fwww.kiosban.com%252Ff4bed3cb%26domain%3Dwww.kiosban.com%26relation%3Dparent.parent&extended_social_context=false&locale=en_US&login_text=&max_rows=1&one_click=false&sdk=joey&show_faces=true&show_login_face=false&size=small&tense=past&width=200. Domains, protocols and ports must match.
 zYYvIvm5_Za.js:89
g.categories.(anonymous function).(anonymous function) zYYvIvm5_Za.js:89
(anonymous function) BOwYwRudgQC.js:5
n _xZSy89IRtb.js:22
h.inform _xZSy89IRtb.js:25
v zYYvIvm5_Za.js:27
p
```

any idea about my problem??

Comment: are you including jquery in your page?

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined <--leads me to believe jquery is not loading properly.

Answer (score 1):

Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined /jangan-nyalakan-lampu-hazard-dikala-hujan-lebat/:1115
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined /jangan-nyalakan-lampu-hazard-dikala-hujan-lebat/:1716

these are because jQuery hasn't loaded correctly, or you are trying to use a jQuery dependent method or selection without jQuery being defined. Make sure you check in what order things are being loaded.

Comment: now when i try to check it again... i get this message...

{"message":"An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.","type":"OAuthException","code":2500}

Answer (score 0):

"Please specify a ShareThis Publisher Key 
For help, contact support@sharethis.com"
I came cross with this error before as well. please check whether you define

```
<script type="text/javascript">        stLight.options({ publisher: "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx" }); </script>
```

Use your actual publisher key in "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx"
After I inserted this into my code, The error gone away.